# Change shadow color of card view

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-cardview

[image: i want the shadow color be like this in image.]
I want the card view shadow be like below image,

Answer (score 1):

CardView shadow color will be on bottom and left side of card (present outside). Based on elevation property you set on card view that much shadow will be visible By default shadow color will be in gray. From your image I found that color you will be needing will be inside the cardView so you must be setting using the background property (using custom image or through designed image in drawable).

Comment: <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="9"
                    android:background="#F44336"
                    app:cardElevation="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            > i tried but it not changing the shadow color

Comment: As mentioned shadow color will be gray by default can't be changed directly. You have to use a separate drawable image and set it as a background.